# VBA Excel создание связей

Tags: excel, vba, link, связи

Необходимо средствами `VBA` создать относительную связь.

**Пример**:

> Есть родительская папка `"NoName"`, в ней файл `noName.xls` и 4 папки:
>   `"first"`, `"second"`, `"third"`, `"fourth"`. В каждой папке есть файл
>   `"class1.xls"`. Надо чтобы в ячейке `А1` `noName.xls` был результат сложения
>   ячеек `А1` из каждого файла `class1.xls`, находящихся в подпапках.

Если я делаю через запись макроса, то связь получается такая:

```
Cells(1, 1) = "='[1first.xls]first'!E1"
```

Как я понимаю, он создаёт связь с открытым файлом если такой имеется. Но как создать формулу, где складываются связи файлов с одинаковыми именами? Ведь нельзя открывать одинаково именованные файлы. При этом родительская папка со всеми вложенными файлами постоянно меняет своё месторасположение и файлы в подпапках `"first"`, `"second"`... заменяются аналогичными, но с другими значениями.

Comment: Одинаковые имена это запрет экселя. Его не обойти. Файлы придется либо переименовать каким-либо образом. Либо сделать что то еще более сложное. Например объединить все в один файл.

Comment: Былоб здорово, если была такая возможность. Но работодатель такого не простит. До меня тут сидело двое обезьянок и вводило формулы вручную по 2 недели. Я хотел это оптимизировать но увы.

Comment: Вы ничего толком не объяснили. Как они формулы вводили если два файла сразу открыть нельзя. Открывали по очереди и данные записывали как значения. Или что?

Comment: Прошу прощения=) Они брали файл куда нужно вводить данные, брали ячейку формул, туда вставляли ссылку на первый файл, открыв его заранее, далее закрыв добавленный файл открывали одноимёнца и к той ссылке приплюсовывали новый. И так 495 файлов с сотнями формул ссылающимися на 5900 внешних источников.

Comment: 495 файлов и 5900 внешних источников - работники с ума не сошли от такого разнообразия и обезьяньей работы? Давно уже пора задуматься об оптимизации, даже если не переходить на другие программы и оставить все в Excel. От многих связей (большинства) можно избавиться, передать эту работу в VBA. Иначе может настать "веселый" момент, когда все рухнет.

Comment: Еще одна ложка дегтя: папки меняют расположение. Создается впечатление, что работодатель - или изощренный садист, или совершенно ничего не понимающий ни структурировании, ни в хранении данных. Обычно стремятся уменьшить количество рутинной работы, чтобы высвободить человеко-часы и, что важнее для руководства, - свести к минимуму возможные ошибки, вызванные человеческим фактором. В Вашей организации все наоборот...

Comment: Дальше. [1first.xls]first'!E1 - ссылка на открытую книгу. При закрытой книге в формуле прописывается весь путь, начиная от корневой папки. Минимум 4 таких ссылки в одной формуле. Количество символов может превысить допустимый порог - формула неработоспособна. /===/ По задаче: попросить макрос (кнопкой, таймером, событием) поочередно открывать файлы и суммировать значения. Так принимается? Без создания связей, без прописывания формул.

Comment: Вопрос я этот решил и даже не стал открывать файлы, циклом пробегался по словарю файлов и из него генерировал полный путь для формулы, а excel слава богу сам соображает когда папку перекинули на другой комп и редактирует пути.
И да на вопрос оптимизации и создания простой веб формы с выгрузкой любого отчёта мне сказали следующее - "А чем мы тогда будет заниматься следующие пол года?".